# ActiveRecord performing join backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am new to Rails and Ruby in general and assume this is a fairly simple setup problem.  I have two models, `food` and `measurement`, they are as below:

**Food:** `name`, `serving_size`, `measurement_id`, `[...]`

**Measurement**: `name`

**food.rb**

```
has_one :measurement
```

**measurement.rb**

```
has_many :foods
```

(I've also tried: *food:* `belongs_to :measurement` and *measurement:* `belongs_to_many` and a bunch of other scenarios)

I'm trying to display the measurement name property based on the `food.measurement_id`, in SQL it would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Food
JOIN Measurement on Food.measurement_id = Measurement.id
```

I've tried simply putting this in my markup: `<%= @food.measurement.name %>`, but the generated SQL seems backwards to me:

> no such column: measurements.food_id: SELECT  "measurements".* FROM "measurements"  WHERE "measurements"."food_id" = ? LIMIT 1

I've also tried a number of different joins in my controller, all of which gave similar errors or errors which told me I was nowhere close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `foods` has a `measurement_id` column, then Food belongs_to measurement and a Measurement has many foods:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :measurement
end

class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foods
end
```

Now when you print the food's measurement name

```
<%= @food.measurement.name %>
```

The generated SQL will look something like

```
SELECT `measurements`.* FROM `measurements` WHERE `measurements`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```